# Response from retrofit is null when Spring Boot server has fulfilled the request

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I have the following code for my retrofit code:

SwapItApi.kt

```
interface SwapItApi {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("customer/add")
    fun addCustomer(@Body customerData: Customer): Call<Customer>
}

object ServiceBuilder {
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.4.29:8102/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T = retrofit.create(service)
}
```

SwapItApiService.kt

```
class SwapItApiService {
    fun addUser(customerData: Customer, onResult: (Customer?) -> Unit) {
        val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(SwapItApi::class.java)

        retrofit.addCustomer(customerData).enqueue(
            object: Callback<Customer> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Customer>, t: Throwable) {
                    onResult(null)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Customer>, response: Response<Customer>) {
                    val customer = response.body()

                    onResult(response.body())
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

RegistrationContent.kt

```
...
private fun addCustomer(customerData: Customer, scope: CoroutineScope, snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState) {
    val apiService = SwapItApiService()

    var convertedDOB = ""

    convertedDOB += customerData.dob!!.substring(4, 8)
    convertedDOB += "-"
    convertedDOB += customerData.dob!!.substring(2, 4)
    convertedDOB += "-"
    convertedDOB += customerData.dob!!.substring(0, 2)



    val customer = Customer(
        id = null,
        username = customerData.username,
        password = customerData.password,
        dob = convertedDOB,
        firstName = customerData.firstName,
        lastName = customerData.lastName,
        isActive = null,
    )

    apiService.addUser(customer) {
        if(it?.id != null) {
            scope.launch {
                snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("ID: ${it.id}, Username: ${it.username}")
            }
        }
        else {
            scope.launch {
                snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Error registering new customer.")
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

So when I call `RegistrationContent.addCustomer(...)`, it calls `SwapItApiService.addCustomer(...)` which returns successfully and when looking at my database table, the entry I've sent has been created, however, `RegistrationContent.addCustomer(...)`'s snackbar displays "Error registering new customer".

After breakpointing, I found that `it?.id` is null. So my code does not seem to be waiting.

I'm new to this so I'm unsure what to do in order to get this to work properly.

Comment: seems like a problem with parsing the response or something like that. Check the response you get from api with something like okhttp logging interceptor to see if it's what you expect and if gson can parse it. Checking the throwable you get in `onFailure` should help as well.

Comment: OnFailure is not the problem here, OnSuccess is called, however because it's asynchronous, it?.id ends up being null instead of the response returned from my server (which I'm able to see when I breakpoint OnSuccess

Comment: I don't see how would the fact that it's asynchronous affect this. `it` is object created by gson, so I think that gson has a problem parsing the id from response.

Comment: As @JanBína mentioned, try to log the raw response and see if it matches your data class. Gson does not throw any exceptions for unknown or missing fields, so if the JSON data does not match you might end up with `null` values. Also since this is an Android project, make sure you have R8 configured properly to not rename or shrink the class, see also [Gson Android example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/README.md).

Comment: As side note: Gson mainly targets Java programs. It might work fine for Kotlin in most cases, but for some situations it does not work very well, e.g. null-safety, see for example [this issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1657). Maybe consider using a JSON library with explicit Kotlin support instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after quite a bit of tinkering (and I mean a lot), it turns out that I as

> As side note: Gson mainly targets Java programs. It might work fine for Kotlin in most cases, but for some situations it does not work very well, e.g. null-safety, see for example this issue. Maybe consider using a JSON library with explicit Kotlin support instead. –
> Marcono1234

Had stated, I needed to change over to Jackson. I then realised that in my `Customer` class, I was not using `@JsonProperty` on the relevant entries... Oh and I also needed to add a `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` with my response from the server and with some buts within `Customer` after adding them, it now works as expected.